# Mysql query only showing rows affected and not the table

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

The following query is only returning rows affected and not the table.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
 SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
  'max(case when department = ''',
  department,
  ''' then questionValue end) ',
  department
)
) INTO @sql 
FROM
jos_survey_submission_values;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  questionNumber AS "", category AS Category, dimension AS Dimension, subDimension AS `Sub-Dimension`, ', @sql, ' 
              FROM jos_survey_submission_values 
              WHERE company_id = "180"
               GROUP BY category, dimension, subDimension, questionNumber
               ORDER BY questionNumber ASC');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

What can I do to get it to return the table?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This looks like it should return the table.

Comment: Are you sure there are rows for that company ID?

Comment: Yes. There are results for that company ID. It works in MYSQL Workbench by not when I try to display the results in my Joomla site.

Comment: This code must be a part of stored procedure. *It works in MYSQL Workbench by not when I try to display the results in my Joomla site.* Maybe workbench adds a lot of code rows because it knows that you need in stored procedure?